# pass data from view to controller in asp.net mvc using ajax

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-mvc-ajax

I want to pass form data from a view to controller action. But I am getting a problem that after clciking the button , which calls the ajax method , nothing is happening. This is my ajax code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function insert()
    {
        var id = document.getElementById("ID").value;
        var name = document.getElementById("Name").value;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("Create","Home")',
            data: { ID: id, Data: name }
        }).done(function (msg) {
            alert("Data Saved: " + msg);
        });
   }
</script>
```

Home is a controller and Create is its method. My controllers code :

```
public string Create(int id , string name)
        {
            return name;
        }
```

After clicking the submit button , nothing is hapeening i.e. contorller is not returning the value of "name". I need help in this , thanks in advance

Comment: did you check request and response in firebug or chrome network tab

Comment: It is giving this exception "System.Web.Mvc.HttpAntiForgeryException: The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present."

Comment: remove attribute [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] from your controller